# Array sort order on Parse Query & Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

hope you're able to help me.
I'm building an App like Tinder, therefore im doing a Parse Query for Users and copy them in an Array. Their profile Images are downloaded also, written in an seperate Array.

```
for object in objects(
UserArray.addObject ....
userPicture.getDataInBacgroundWithBlock({  
(imageData: NSData!, error NSError!) -> Void in
UserImageArray.append(UIImage(data: data))
```

Unfortunately the image-Files in UserImageArray are unsorted and in a different Order than the Users of UserArray.

I Need the same order in both Arrays, as their data will be combined by showing a User Card.
Why and how and what should I do??
I need to download and cache all the files, to provide fast data delivery.

Thanks for your help....

Comment: is there a better way to do this ? sounds fragile to me

Comment: Yep, not great - but the only way to download Images from Parse.com

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Sort NSDictionary using following code
 var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "KeynameIn_jsonObject", ascending: true)
 UserArray = (objects.allKeys as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I'm still not able to get it right. The Image Array contains just UIImage Files i.e.: <UIImage: 0x123456>, {640, 640}. How should i sort this Array to match the Indexes of the PFUser Array?

Comment: Whats also very strange - On the second time I'm doing the query the sorting order is correct (as it gets the same Images from the Cache, maybe?!)

Comment: Hi.. please refer following link for more detail:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000208/how-to-sort-uiimages-by-date-from-application-folder-in-ios

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Perfect tip!! Thanks!